# Getting DPM Alerts for Failed Recovery Point for Database that has Been Deleted

Tags: sharepoint, dpm

Deleted a defunct database in SharePoint, now getting alerts from DPM saying:

The following alert occurred at 2/16/2016 12:16:54 PM.

Status: Active
Data source type: 
Data source: SharePointServer\Database_I_Just_Deleted 
Computer: SharePointServer
Description: Last 1 recovery points not created.

For more information, open DPM Administrator Console and review the alert details in the Monitoring task area.

---

Cannot find where to disable monitoring of this deleted database.

Comment: How did you delete the database? Through SharePoint or in SQL Server?

Comment: Through SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

DPM is checking the consistency of the SharePoint meta-base, which is not consistent anymore due to you deleting the database in SQL Server. That is, you have removed the logical/physical database in SQL Server but you have not removed references to it from the SharePoint metadata. My advice to you is to restore the database that you deleted and then remove it correctly via the SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets.

There is a really good article on removing orphaned databases here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30558.sharepoint-2013-deleting-orphaned-sharepoint-databases.aspx

And a list of all database-related cmdlets can be found here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee906544.aspx